# Is there a way to limit cookies to certain hosts in HTTP?

Tags: web-application, http, cookies, nginx, content-security-policy

Using Nginx, I hope to restrict the permissible hosts for cookies. My initial intention was to employ a Content Security Policy for this purpose, but I don't see an obvious way to do this via a CSP. Ideally I'd find something like

```
Restrict-Cookies-Header: hostname1.tld hostname2.tld2
```

Can something like this be accomplished with HTTP headers? Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to restrict what hosts the browser will send your cookies to, or restrict what 3rd party sites can set cookies?

Comment: Restrict what 3rd party resources can set cookies

Comment: @Alex: The basic design of how cookies work includes already that domain A cannot set or read a cookie for domain B. So it is unclear for me what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Well, the situation was that I had an iframe to a 3rd party site that set tracking cookies (on its own domain). I did not want my users to be tracked like that. It turns out I can accomplish this by setting the sandbox property of the iframe. I should have been clearer about my actual use case, sorry!